# getElementById after conditionally rendering with setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a trigger button that will open a dialog asking if a user would like to enable text to speech. Once the dialog is open, I want to focus on the yes button within the dialog by getting the button element by its ID.

When the trigger is pressed, the following function is called:

```
  private openTTSDialog = () => {
    if (this.state.ttsDialog === true) {
      this.setState({ ttsDialog: false })
    } else {
      this.setState({ ttsDialog: true }, () => {
        // search document once setState is finished
        const yesButton = document.getElementById('tts-dialog-yes-button')
        log('yesButton', yesButton)
        if (yesButton) {
          yesButton.focus()
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

And my dialog is conditionally rendered with a ternary expression like this:

```
{
  this.state.ttsDialog ? (
    <div className="tts-dialog-container">
      <div className="tts-dialog-text-container">
        {session.ttsEnabled ? (
          <div>
            {
              strings.disableTTS
            }
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            {
              strings.enableTTS
            }
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="tts-dialog-button-container">
        <button
          aria-label={strings.yes}
          tabIndex={0}
          className="tts-dialog-button"
          id="tts-dialog-yes-button"     // this is the button I want to focus
          onClick={this.toggleTTS}
        >
          {
            strings.yes
          }
        </button>
        <button
          aria-label={strings.no}
          tabIndex={0}
          className="tts-dialog-cancelButton"
          onClick={this.closeTTSDialog}
        >
          {
            strings.no
          }
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : null
}
```

My log for `yesButton` is undefined. I thought adding the callback function to setState would fix this because I would be searching the document after setState was finished, but I'm still missing something. Any idea what it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the constructor of your class, you should add a ref to your button:
`this.myRef = React.createRef();`
Then in your button :

```
<button
          ref={this.myRef}
          aria-label={strings.yes}
          tabIndex={0}
          className="tts-dialog-button"
          id="tts-dialog-yes-button"     // this is the button I want to focus
          onClick={this.toggleTTS}
        >
```

Finally, instead of doing:

```
const yesButton = document.getElementById('tts-dialog-yes-button')
```

You should do :

```
const yesButton = = this.myRef.current;
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I would also think this should work since you use a callback on `setState`, so the new render should have completed and the element should already be mounted and accessible. Anyway I think the idiomatic React way for this would be to use a ref (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) and put it on the button like `<button ref={this.yesButton} ...>...</button>` and then call `this.yesButton.focus()`. Have you tried that already?